# MYSQL Database Connection to ASPX website using C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, mysql, database, connection

Can anyone write a simple example of how to connect from my ASPX website to my Database? 
I'm just starting in ASP, so please keep it simple.

MysqlDB Name :  ASP
Class :  Database.cs

Comment: http://www.codeguru.com/csharp/.net/net_data/article.php/c19407/A-StepbyStep-Guide-To-Using-MySQL-with-ASPNET--Part-1.htm

Comment: Welcome to SO. It often helps to show what you've already tried.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

maybe this will help

first of all you need to include some reference you can download them at this link: http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/net/

here is the code:

```
using MySql.Data.MysqlClient;

namespace OwnNameSpace
{
  public class Database
  {
    MySqlConnection connect;
    string connection = "Data Source=localhost;Database=ASP;User ID=(your ID)";
//constructor
public Database()
{
}

  // this if want to select something in your db
  public MySqlDataReader Select(string query)
  {

      connect = new MySqlConnection(connection);
      connect.Close();
      MySqlCommand command = connect.CreateCommand();
      command.CommandText = query;
      connect.Open();
      MySqlDataReader reader;
      return reader = command.ExecuteReader();
  }

  // this if want to insert/delete or update 
  public Boolean Modify(string query)
  {

      connect = new MySqlConnection(connection);
      MySqlCommand command = connect.CreateCommand();
      command.CommandText = query;
      connect.Open();
      try
      {
         command.ExecuteNonQuery();
         return true;
      }
      catch
      {
        return false;
      }

   }



 }
}
```

Comment: You'll need to make sure that all of your MySqlDataReader, MySqlConnection, and MySqlCommand objects are properly disposed of.